# What is the default time zone of PHP time()

Tags: php, function, time

I am new to PHP and I tested the `time()` function from PHP.

```
echo Date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
02-12-2014 19:25:32
```

However, the actual time at my current place is `03-12-2014 02:25:32`
It seems that the `time()` function is 7 hrs before my timezone.

**My question is:** What is the default time zone of `time()` in PHP? Which country's timezone is it using? What determines the timezone, is it related to the server I am using?

Please cut me some slack if you find this extremenly easy `:-(`

Comment: If you turn on PHP's error reporting/display errors, it will often be complaining about a blank value for `date.timezone` in php.ini.  Look there to see if your PHP installation came with a value specified.  Also `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your test code to see if PHP is reporting an error regarding it.

Comment: The "time" take the server/pc date. See how many hours is setted for you, it's based on your timezone.

Comment: *What determines the timezone, is it related to the srever I am using?* - short answer, yes ;)

Comment: When `date.timezone` is not set in php.ini, the warning provides your answer: "_Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone._"